# PDO query with params

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to PDO and I am trying to perform a query.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbmeseros WHERE alias_mesero=:alias AND res_mesero=:rest');

$stmt->execute(array(':alias'=>$alias,
                  ':rest'=>$rest));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if( ! $row)
{
//to do when the query is empty
}
else if ($row)
{
//to do when the query is not empty
}
```

The query is executed, but the conditions are not met.

What I need is that when there are no results for the query, the next step must be //to do when the query is empty.

But the query is not empty but the condition :

```
if( ! $row)
{
//to do when the query is empty
}
```

is executed...

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

EDITED QUESTION

I have changed my code and it is working now.
This is my new code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT alias_mesero
    FROM tbmeseros
    WHERE alias_mesero = :alias AND rest_mesero = :rest';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':alias'=> $alias, ':rest' =>$rest));

$red = $sth->fetchAll();
//echo count($red);
if(count($red)==0) 
{
  //to do if query results are 0
}
else 
{
// to do if query results are >0
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is it an issue with your logic or the query?

Comment: @Ibu, thank you for your comment. I am checking the query with real values, and with the given values, the query result should be that there are records on the table that met the conditions. The problem is that the if condition that is executed is if (!$row){...} May be the logic is wrong.

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` after you fetch the results.

Comment: Ask yourself, "what is `$row` once it is equal to `$stmt->fetch....`?".

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I have found a solution for my issue, please see my updated question.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be faster to retrieve the results as an array using fetchAll and perform `count` on it to see if it's empty. An empty resultset is not false as you seem to assume.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($rows)==0)   {
//to do when the query is empty
}  else {
//to do when the query is not empty
}
```

Comment: @amenadiel,I have found a solution for my issue, please see my updated question. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, what part of my answer deserved a negative vote? It seems that using ```fetchAll``` and ```count``` finally got the code working. ¿You assume that any answer you don't like means the person didn't read the question? Not nice at all.